# acl9 and devise don't seem to work well together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization, devise, acl9

I have a user model whose access controlled by ACL9.

in `UsersController`:

```
#ACL9 related stuff
before_filter :load_user, :only => [:show]
  access_control do
    allow :owner, :of => :user, :to => [:show]
  end

def load_user
  user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

in `ApplicationController`:

```
rescue_from 'Acl9::AccessDenied', :with => :access_denied

def access_denied
  authenticate_user! # a method from Devise
end
```

It is no problem to type in url for sign in page `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in`, but it is a problem when for example I type in the user page first, which I am to expect to be redirected to sign in page automatically through the logic above.

`http://localhost:3000/users/1` => infinite redirect hell. It tries to redirect back to `users/1` again instead of directing to `users/sign_in`.

Does anyone have an opinion as to what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not use Acl9 in Devise user controller. Since you are not authenticated you have no rights and you will not authenticate :D.
You may want to forbid users to delete, so it should be like:

```
access_control :only => [:destroy] do
      allow :admin
end
```

For UsersController you should overwrite your access_control if you want to leave it as is in application controller.